# How to search and copy particular pattern from a file to another file

Tags: regex, sed, awk, notepad++

i have a file like this

```
MY-27125:some text
MY-27132:some text
MY-26565:some text
some text
MY-26097:some text
MY-27129:some text
MY-27211  && MY-26565:some text
some another text
MY-27175/MY-27147:some text
MY-27159\MY-27149:some text
MY-26747,MY-26945:some text
MY-20811 MY-26889:some text
```

i want to use sed or notepad++ or awk to have only text starting with MY-[5 digit number].

Output should be like below

```
MY-27125
MY-27132
MY-26565
MY-26097
MY-27129
MY-27211
MY-27175
MY-27159
MY-26747
MY-20811
MY-26565
MY-27147
MY-27149
MY-26945
MY-26889
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: this works fine grep -oP 'MY-\d{5}' file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grep is the right tool:

```
grep -oP 'MY-\d{5}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu awk`

```
awk 'NR>1 {print RS substr($0,1,5)}' RS="MY-" file
MY-27125
MY-27132
MY-26565
MY-26097
MY-27129
MY-27211
MY-26565
MY-27175
MY-27147
MY-27159
MY-27149
MY-26747
MY-26945
MY-20811
MY-26889
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n "/\(MY-[0-9]\{5\}\).*/ s//\1/p" YourFile
```

add -posix on GNU sed

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '^MY-' < in.txt | cut -b1-8 
MY-27125
MY-27132
MY-26565
MY-26097
MY-27129
MY-27211
MY-27175
MY-27159
MY-26747
MY-20811
```

Comment: Note that this will not print the second `MY-` on lines like `MY-26747,MY-26945:some text`.